# php unable to select data

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, zend-studio

I'm trying to select a SINGLE value from the mysql database. I have run the query in phpmyadmin and it work great. But when I echo the $result, I get nothing... by the way,for the database and password I use xxx because I don't want to show it... My insert query works very well

Thanks

```
<?php

//Create Connection
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "xxx";
$dbname = "xxx";



//Connect
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT StartPriceUnder FROM YJ_Value";
$result = $conn->query($sql);



echo hi;
echo $result;
echo ya;

$conn->close();

?>
```

Comment: You can't just echo `$result` like that. You need to fetch the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "xxx";
$dbname = "xxx";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT StartPriceUnder FROM YJ_Value";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
// output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "StartPriceUnder:" . $row["StartPriceUnder"];
    }
} 
else {
    echo "0 results";
}
    $conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: For reference: http://www.w3schools.com

Comment: Now you have a reference, code, but no explanation what you changed and why you changed it and what was wrong with OP's code

Comment: it's because he didn't fetch the result..

Comment: I just added the if-else statement and the while loop to output each row..  And he can't just echo the `$result` like that..

Comment: Thank you very much, your code work very well!

Comment: one more question. When I do echo $row["StartPriceUnder"]; or $result=$row["StartPriceUnder"], it doesn't work

Comment: I think I figure out, I have to put the $result command within the while statement

Comment: but when i put the echo $result outside of while statement it won't echo 0 0

Comment: you mean, you will assign the `$row["StartPriceUnder"]` in a `$result` variable? yes, you have to put it inside the while loop. But if the result of the query is more than one then you have to put it also in an array and echo it using while loop.

Comment: maybe you can use other variable because `$result` is already used and for you not to be confused of the variables.

Answer (score 0):

You have to fetch your result, so do something like this:

```
$row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

After this you can echo it like this:

```
echo $row["StartPriceUnder"];
```

For more information about `fetch_array()` see the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php

Comment: Please explain downvote so I can learn from it!